# Django decorators to handle admin users redirection

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I want normal users to be redirected to `<address>/panel` and need admins to be redirected to `<adress>/admin`. So what I did in `views.py` is something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@unauthenticated_user
def registration_view(request):
    ...

@unauthenticated_user
def login_view(request):
    ...

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def admin_home_view(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'account/admin/home-page.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['user'])
def user_home_view(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'account/user/home-page.html', context)
```

## Update here

And in `decorators.py` I have:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from groups_manager.models import Group, GroupMemberRole, Member

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('panel')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            allowed_role = allowed_roles[0]
            username = request.user.username
            member = Member.objects.get(username=username)
            roles = GroupMemberRole.objects.filter(groupmember__member=member)
            member_roles = []
            for role in roles:
                member_roles.append(role.label)
            if 'admin' in member_roles:
                ...
            elif 'user' in member_roles:
                ...
            else:
                return HttpResponse('you are not allowed')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

I want to know how I can redirect `admin` users to `<address>/admin` url. But admin users are redirected to `/panel` url.

My `urls.py` is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin', views.admin_home_view, name='admin'),


    path('panel', views.user_home_view, name='panel'),

    path('panel/register', views.registration_view, name='register'),
    path('panel/logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('panel/login', views.login_view, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Put a your redirect on `login_view`, after you've authenticated the request you know where to send them.

Comment: Should I completely get rid of decorators? I would be thankful if you answer seperately

Comment: @markwalker_ I updated the question. I tried to append all roles to a list an then try to redirect them. How can I tell it in login_view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html) because it is a great app for handling these type of user/auth scenarios with it's decorators and mixins (but this would require you to switch to class based views for the later).

You could/should override django's `LoginView` which you can see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L38) and do something like;

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as DjangoLogin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class LoginView(DjangoLogin):
    """ Custom Login """

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
        user = form.get_user()
        auth_login(self.request, user)

        # Do your permissions check here
        if user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/panel')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I think based on @markwalker_ help.

Now my `decorators.py` is:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('panel')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func
```

and in my `login_view` I have:

```
login(request, user)
member = Member.objects.get(username=username)
roles = GroupMemberRole.objects.filter(groupmember__member=member)
member_roles = []
for role in roles:
    member_roles.append(role.label)
if 'admin' in member_roles:
    return redirect('admin')
else:
    return redirect('panel')
```

I think it could be a reliable way to work.